# Html tags not rendering inside div (ckeditor)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor to get what user has inputed in the textarea , but when I want to show/render that field in my page it just shows the html tags not the rendered one ! 
It's odd cause even tags aren't escaped and everything looks like a pure html syntax which is just not rendered !
what is stored in mongodb is this :

```
"longDesc" : "<p style=\"text-align: left;\">We need creation of <strong>7 animated banners</strong>.</p>\n\n<p style=\"text-align: left;\">We need to remake to dynamic form. We provide you open source data and technical specifications.</p>\n"
```

and am using angularjs double brace in view to show this expression .

```
{{job.longDesc}}
```

and the output exactly is :

```
<p style=\"text-align: left;\">We need creation of <strong>7 animated banners</strong>.</p>\n\n<p style=\"text-align: left;\">We need to remake to dynamic form. We provide you open source data and technical specifications.</p>\n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml). You just need to:

```
$scope.myHTML = '<p>test</p>';

....

<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```

You will need to include the ngSanitize in your app dependency to make the ng-bind-html work. Here is an Plunker example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/RRNyiwQAaHQfNqtHslCD?p=preview

Comment: It doesn't show anything ! the attribute of <p> tag changes to ng-binding but it doesn't return any value. Even I tested using a filter to return $sce.trustAsHtml(text) but it didn't work . Ng-bind-html-unsafe didn't work, camel case worked neither .

Comment: eddited my answer with an example